# Transition animation when click event is made between two divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Click on the key here and I want a div to come after here. How can I do it ?

how can i do this with jquery

https://streamable.com/ai5c9d  // I want to do it like here

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="Test1">
        <div class="Lock">
    </div>
     
    </body>
    </html>

    .Test1  {
    position: fixed;
    width: 285px;
    height: 580px;
    right: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
     background-color: rgb(24, 89, 173); 
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.Lock {
        position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    height: 6px;
    right: 72.5px;
    bottom: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information such as what you want to click specifically and more details about what you want the result to be of clicking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of styles for positioning and [jQuery.animate()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp) for the tweening.

```js
let isBig = true;
$(".Lock").click(function() {
  console.log('d')
  let style = isBig ? {
    height: "200px",
    width: "300px"
  } : {
    height: "20px",
    width: "20px"
  }
  isBig = !isBig
  $('.box').animate(
    style, 500);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  background: #333;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.Test1 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 285px;
  height: 580px;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(24, 89, 173);
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.Lock {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 6px;
  right: 72.5px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>

  <div class="Test1">
    <div class="Lock"></div>
  </div>
  <div class='box'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thnaks, How can I find page transition animations on an iOS phone. I want to use different page transitions when switching between jquery and both divs.

Comment: Not sure - depending on if you want a full solution for an app like experience, or a one off for this single usage there are many options. For a one off, the jquery animate does what you need. For navigation and app-like experience, I use ionic and angular when I create hybrid apps. However, if this answer helped solve your exact question, would you mind marking it as the accepted answer? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it solved my problem for now, but I need a resource where I can see varieties of animation that I can do with normal jquery.